# Is there a way to change size of ng-cicle-progress CircleProgressComponent element dynamically?

Tags: css, angular, typescript

In the Angular 11 project I need to change ng-circle-progress library CircleProgressComponent element size dynamically.

I have found out, that size of the element can be changed by putting width/height CSS properties on the child DOM element - svg. Problem is that svg doesn't have any id or class values, so even if I could somehow query the element, this would be not that easy and flexible as it should be.

Would be extremely nice to have a parameter in the CircleProgressComponent, that listens to outer variable changes and re-renders the element with a new size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had never used this library, so I've read their [doc](https://github.com/bootsoon/ng-circle-progress/blob/master/projects/ng-circle-progress/README.md) and thier [demo page](https://bootsoon.github.io/ng-circle-progress/).
If I understand, they have the parameter that you want called `radius`

```
<circle-progress
  [percent]="85"
  [radius]="200" // the size you want
  [outerStrokeWidth]="16"
  [innerStrokeWidth]="8"
  [outerStrokeColor]="'#78C000'"
  [innerStrokeColor]="'#C7E596'"
  [animation]="true"
  [animationDuration]="300"
></circle-progress>
```